# Unable to add Selenium library in Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

So I installed Python, Pycharm and Selenium

Pycharm still unable to show selenium even though Selenium is installed.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Edge
```

Look at the screenshot.

It had happened before, but then I was able to click "install/ad selenium" etc and then it worked. But I dont see any more option.

What are the other options to add this?[image]

Comment: how did you install it? from pycharm project settings, from pip, conda? do you have more than one virtual/conda environment? is the interpreter set to the environment where you installed it

Comment: Seems like you don't have python setup correctly for your project. Set the correct python path and it will list modules you had installed

Comment: I installed it using pip and the environment is set correctly. I also see Selenium directory within my python folder. Where in Pycharm can i see all the installed modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

At the time of creating project, I was not checking the box to "inherit global site-package", as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import **Chrome** module separately. **Chrome** module is included within the **webdriver** module as follows :

[image: WebDriver_variants]

In your code you need to import the **webdriver** only as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I understand. But Pycharm is not recognizing selenium . So when I i write "from selenium"; It does not recognize selenium as an available libraryr/module